# How can i extrude a stl with python

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to convert `png` images to 3d `stls`. I finally found a way to do that. But there is a problem. Now the exported image has no z value no thickness. The way I am doing it is for the white pixels on the image I draw triangles to a surface.

```
def define_faces(numpy_array, column_number, row_number, z_value):
    print("Vertices Initializing.")
    vertices = np.zeros((row_number , column_number , 3))
    for x in range(0, column_number):
        for y in range(0, row_number):
            z = z_value
            vertices[y][x] = (x,y,z)
    print("Vertices Initialized")
    faces = []
    print("Initializing Faces.")
    for x in range(0, column_number - 1):
        for y in range(0, row_number - 1):
            if numpy_array[y][x] >= PIXEL_COLOR_FILTER:
                vertice1 = vertices[y][x]
                vertice2 = vertices[y+1][x]
                vertice3 = vertices[y+1][x+1]
                face1 = np.array([vertice1, vertice2, vertice3])

                vertice1 = vertices[y][x]
                vertice2 = vertices[y][x+1]
                vertice3 = vertices[y+1][x+1]
                face2 = np.array([vertice1,vertice2,vertice3])
                faces.append(face1)
                faces.append(face2)
    print("Faces Initialized")
    return np.array(faces) , faces
```

and

```
def create_mesh(faces_numpy, faces, output_name):
    print("Creating Mesh.")
    surface = mesh.Mesh(np.zeros(faces_numpy.shape[0], dtype = mesh.Mesh.dtype))
    for i ,f in enumerate(faces):
        for j in range(3):
            surface.vectors[i][j] = faces_numpy[i][j]
            
    surface.save(output_name)
    print("Mesh created succesfully.")
```

These are the core functions of this code. Code is originally for `Lithophane` generation. I have an idea on instead of giving triangles and making them an `stl`, directly generating cubes on intended pixels. so it becomes 3d. But before that any ideas on how to extrude the final `stl`?

This is the png:

[image: This is the png]

This is the stl:

[image: This is the stl]

Comment: You need two z values.

Comment: Hi. I tried to give two z values. I called the define_faces function twice and initialized their outputs to 4 separate variable. Then I tried to combine those outputs with append function. But it raise this error. "IndexError: index 20506 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 20506" in 6th line of create_mesh function. This line: "surface.vectors[i][j] = faces_numpy[i][j]".

Answer (score 1):

You can use open source library [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib#python-integration) with python bindings to solve your task.

Then the code for extrusion is as follows:

```py
import meshlib.mrmeshpy as mr
# load image as Distance Map object:
dm = mr.loadDistanceMapFromImage(mr.Path("your-image.png"), 0)
# find boundary contour of the letter:
polyline2 = mr.distanceMapTo2DIsoPolyline(dm, isoValue=127)
# triangulate the contour
mesh = mr.triangulateContours(polyline2.contours2())
# extrude itself:
mr.addBaseToPlanarMesh(mesh, zOffset=30)
# export the result:
mr.saveMesh(mesh, mr.Path("output-mesh.stl"))
```

The result will look as
[image]

Comment: it doesn't work at all, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74862109/extruding-an-stl-from-a-binary-png-image-with-python

Comment: The answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75066059/7325599) states that it does work, and the error comes from failed file opening.

Comment: The relevant method addBaseToPlanar did work for me. I did something slightly different, but related.