# Extruding an STL from a binary png image with python

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, mesh

I have been working on this code for a project at work which will (hopefully) take in images from a scanning electron microscope and generate 3D STL files of the structures were imaging. I'm at the stage with the code where I'm trying to generate a 3D structure from a 'coloured in' binary image I've made with some edge detection code I wrote. I came across this post [How can i extrude a stl with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73105412/how-can-i-extrude-a-stl-with-python) that basically does exactly what I need (generating a meshed 3D structure from a binary image). I've tried using/adapting the code in the answer to that post (see below) but I keep running into the following error: `polyline2 = mr.distanceMapTo2DIsoPolyline(dm.value(), isoValue=127) RuntimeError: Bad expected access`. I cant find anything online about why this is happening and I'm no expert in Python so have no idea myself. If anyone has an idea, I'd really appreciate it!

Code from answer to above post:

```
import meshlib.mrmeshpy as mr
# load image as Distance Map object:
dm = mr.loadDistanceMapFromImage(mr.Path("your-image.png"), 0)
# find boundary contour of the letter:
polyline2 = mr.distanceMapTo2DIsoPolyline(dm.value(), isoValue=127)
# triangulate the contour
mesh = mr.triangulateContours(polyline2.contours2())
# extrude itself:
mr.addBaseToPlanarMesh(mesh, zOffset=30)
# export the result:
mr.saveMesh(mesh, mr.Path("output-mesh.stl"))
```

I have tried the following:

- Reconfigured the MeshLib package that this command uses. Package docs here: https://meshinspector.github.io/MeshLib/html/index.html#PythonIntegration
- Updating VS studio/python/MeshLib

Answer (score 0):

**In older version of meshlib** python module `RuntimeError: Bad expected access` indicated that `mr.loadDistanceMapFromImage` had failed, you should had checked it like this:

```py
import meshlib.mrmeshpy as mr
# load image as Distance Map object:
dm = mr.loadDistanceMapFromImage(mr.Path("your-image.png"), 0)

# check dm
if ( not dm.has_value() ):
    raise Exception(dm.error())

# find boundary contour of the letter:
polyline2 = mr.distanceMapTo2DIsoPolyline(dm.value(), isoValue=127)
# triangulate the contour
mesh = mr.triangulateContours(polyline2.contours2())
# extrude itself:
mr.addBaseToPlanarMesh(mesh, zOffset=30)
# export the result:
mr.saveMesh(mesh, mr.Path("output-mesh.stl"))
```

**But in actual release your code will rise exception with real error.**

Please make sure that path is correct, if it doesn't help please provide more info like png file and version of python and version of MeshLib and anything else you find related.

P.S. If there is real problem with [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib) better open [issue in github](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib/issues/new).